# How to Hide/show table div acting on keyup filter input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-filter

I have a number of divs that are listed and I want to be able to add an input field that will allow a user to start typing and the divs are filtered accordinly

I'm trying the code below, but it's not filtering. It's not throwing up any errors either, so I'm not sure what to do at this point...

Here's the html markup:

```
<table class="table" id="tagstable">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><label data-tagid="1" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">hotel tag<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="2" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">yoga tag<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="3" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">jogging tag<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="4" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">exercise tag<span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label data-tagid="5" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">aerobic tag<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="6" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">running tag<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="23" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">Body Building<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="24" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">BB<span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label data-tagid="25" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">one<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="26" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">two<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="27" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">three<span></span></label></td>
         <td><label data-tagid="28" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">four<span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><label data-tagid="29" class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">five<span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filter').keyup(function(){
        var tr = $('#tagstable tbody tr');
        tr.hide();
        tr.filter(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).show();
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/155/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:contains` selector to get the label that has the value from the input field

Do the following:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#filter').keyup(function()
        {
        var val = this.value;
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label:contains('+val+')').closest('td')
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
        })
});
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/3/

Comment: is it possible to add fade in and fade out effect also ??

Comment: fade out for what?

Comment: while displaying the tr values

Comment: thanks a lot ... this is good and works well , thanks once again

Comment: Sorry to say consider this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/2/ , its not working when i type aero it is showing irrelevant results also

Comment: right now it displays all the thags from that tr if you want ony one tag to display you need to select the the tds

Comment: Could you please help i am unable to add case insensitive search .